Is there a way to fetch a list of computer assets from google workspace directory API?
I'm trying to fetch a list of computer assets (Linux, macOS, and Windows) from the Google Workspace Directory API but haven't found any relevant documentation. In the available documentation, there are only options to fetch lists of ChromeOS and mobile assets.
Here's what I've tried so far:
Endpoint Used: mobiledevices.list and chromeosdevices.list
Query Parameters: Tried using computer OS-specific search query parameters.
Despite these efforts, I haven't been able to retrieve the desired devices. Has anyone successfully fetched computer assets using the Google Workspace Directory API? If so, could you please share how you did it or point me to the relevant documentation?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
Additional Information:
API Documentation Reference: Google Workspace Directory API
ChromeOS endpoint: chromeosdevices.list
Mobile devices endpoint: mobiledevices.list
Feel free to suggest any alternative methods or endpoints if fetching computer assets directly is not possible through this API.

Try with the Cloud Identity API https://cloud.google.com/identity/docs/reference/rest#rest-resource:-v1.devices
